# MacOS HighSierra - How to tell Apache to use PHP 7.2.9 instead of PHP 7.1.16

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, gd, php-7.2, macos-high-sierra

In Terminal, if I type “php -v”, I get:
——
PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 22 2018 02:58:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
[php -v in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vLHN.png)
——

In Safari, if I type “localhost/phpinfo.php” (a file containing the line: ), I get:
——
PHP Version 7.1.16
[phpinfo() output in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhL7Y.png)
——

phpMyAdmin is telling me:
Web server

```
• Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) PHP/7.1.16
• Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
• PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
• PHP version: 7.1.16
```

[WebServer infos in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSeun.png)
——

How can I tell Apache to use 7.2.9 instead of 7.1.16?

My goal is to get rid of this error when programming in PHP (Yes, I am a newbie):
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagettfbbox() in /Users/David/Sites/graphic_example.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/David/Sites/graphic_example.php on line 7

——

Can you help me out with a detailed procedure?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm the path that PHP7.2 was installed at.
In most of the cases, it should be `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2`, but may have some differences, if you're not sure, go check the .*shrc(* = your shell, e.g. .zshrc, .bashrc) file, it should have a line like `PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin`.

Second, copy this line(in my case): `usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`, according to the thing I've mentioned in the first step, you might be needed to change something in this line to fit the situation(like different path name) you've met.

Third, edit your Apache config file: `sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
(Also, there might be some differences here, but should not have too much). Then, find the line: `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`. This is the original PHP7 module, which is the 7.1.XX one. We need to comment it out by adding a `#` at the head of this line, make it become `#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`.

Finally, we will add a new line `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so`, the path should come from the second step.

After all the things are done, we can run `sudo apachectl configtest` first to make sure everything is OK or not. Then, run `sudo apachectl restart`, the `phpinfo();` should display the correct PHP version you've assigned.

However, this may not successfully solve your problem. There are still some problems to be solved: PHP configurations needed to be set, PHP-FHM should be set and run.

So, you can easily compare the two `php.ini` files(`/etc/php.ini` and `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini`) through an editor that have a comparison function, to make sure that the new one already set to "normal" status.

Another is to set PHP-FPM, since the built-in PHP already has PHP-FPM function, that means the newer one should also enable this function, otherwise, everything may no go in order. We need to modify the Apache config file again by commenting/uncommenting or adding following lines, you should notice that the 'php7_module' is commented out again, and that's a normal practice.

```
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

After the modification, remember to restart Apache server. Then, run these commands, or just the last one and restart your Mac, then everything should be as usual:

```
sudo /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.conf
```

```
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.2.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.2.plist
```